# In Stripe Billing Portal with Multiple Prices, how do you simplify the Plan Name?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

I am using the integrated [Billing Portal in Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/questions/billing-customer-portal). Using the Node SDK,  I've added several different prices (and their associated products) to a user's Subscription. The same set of prices are added to every user - this is basically a SaaS plan.

If I then use the [Billing Portal](https://support.stripe.com/questions/billing-customer-portal) to provide the end user with information (such as their invoices), the fact that there are multiple prices on a single Subscription becomes confusing to the End user. That's because Stripe, in describing the billing plan, lists all the different products that are included in the subscription.

This description appears under the Stripe Portal's heading "CURRENT PLAN" when the user opens the portal - e.g., using the link obtained through an API call like this:

```
        const getLink = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
            customer: customerId,
            return_url: `${baseFrontEndUrl}/billing/portal/return`
        });
```

The trouble is, the "Current Plan" presented in the Stripe Billing Portal lists all the different prices in the title, so instead of saying, for example, "Pro Plan" the name of the plan simply lists all the different line items that are included in the plan, like, "Cheese Utilization, Hot Sauce Utilization, Bread Utilization," etc.

Instead, I would like the Portal to refer to the CURRENT PLAN by a name, such as "Pro Plan."

Is there a way to label a Stripe Subscription so that the "Current Plan" references a unified plan name, such as "Pro Plan" even though it has multiple line items?

Answer (score 0):

For others who might find this - Stripe's tech support wrote to say this is not possible yet, but is on the roadmap:

> Upon checking with our team, this feature is currently on our roadmap
> for customer portal products. As of the moment, all the names added on
> the line items will reflect as the name of the plan. You may consider
> creating a specific subscription for each product to avoid multiple
> names.
>
> That said, I have filed feedback with our team. I have alerted them
> with this information and they have added it to the queue of issues to
> be addressed. Unfortunately, I do not have a timeline of when this may
> become available.